# Docker port mismatch from inside another container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a simple setup of 2 docker containers, one for the database and one for the web service.

I start the DB docker container like so:

```
docker run -d --name dbs.service -p 5434:5432 -e POSTGRES_DB=my_app -e POSTGRES_USER=my_user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_password postgres:9.6.2
```

This works fine. And from localhost, i can connect to it fine as well (using pgcli for connection)

```
pgcli postgres://my_user:my_password@dbs.service:5434/my_app
```

Now I start the web service container, which works fine

```
docker run -d --name web.service --link dbs.service:dbs.service web-service:latest
```

However here's the problem. From inside the container, I **cannot** connect to DB using port **5434** but I **can** connect to DB using port **5432**.

So I login to container using

```
docker exec -it web.service bash
```

Now this works

```
pgcli postgres://my_user:my_password@dbs.service:5432/my_app
```

but this does not

```
pgcli postgres://my_user:my_password@dbs.service:5434/my_app
```

I can't understand why it can connect to 5432 but not 5434. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you running the first `pgcli` command in your question?  On the host? Inside the `dbs.service` container? Somewhere else?

Comment: on the localhost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-p 5434:5432
```

This option publishes the port for access from outside of the docker host to your container. The host will listen on 5434 and route the traffic through to the container's port 5432.

**However, container-to-container traffic doesn't use that.** Container to container traffic simply needs a common docker network. From there, any container can talk to any other container on the same network. The port used is the container listening port, not the published port on the host. You don't even need to publish the port for it to be accessible by other containers.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I would supplement this with Docker's Networking Documentation: [Docker Networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/)